# (open source) course management web software

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, time-management, educational

I'm looking for a few alternatives for a course management web software.
It should be able to:

- manage courses online
- generate a website with all courses
- allow online booking with an adjustable form

  - aka add custom fields
- manage attendees online
- export to Excel (either xls or csv)
- best to be standalone

I already found:

- [OSG Seminar Manager](http://sman.osg-gmbh.de) (Joomla)
- [Studip](http://studip.de) (standalone, but badly programmed, seems not installable)
- [wp-events-plugin](http://wp-events-plugin.com) (WordPress, adjustable forms not free)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Moodle](https://moodle.net/) would be the software of your choice.

Most online course creators/educators use Moodle recently, and has been evolving pretty fast.

It also has a large community. So, it would be easy to setup and navigate.

I have used a site which is built on Moodle, and it's pretty smooth and very easy to use with a wonderful set of features.

Its features include:

1. Ease of use
2. Personalized Dashboard
3. Intuitive and all-in-one calender
4. Notifications from student activities
5. Really good text editor
6. Tracking progress of students

And a [lot more](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Features).

There are already hundreds of sites in the [US](https://moodle.net/sites/index.php?country=US) itself, which are built on Moodle.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Regpack](http://www.regpacks.com/blog/category/course-registration/).

Allows you to customize fields, manage students with personalized dashboards, and has great reporting tools for every aspect of your data (payments, attendance, sessions registered for, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The well known EDX platform is also open source.
Main page: https://open.edx.org/
Source code at github: https://github.com/edx/
There is also a community around this software and documentation and it can be self hosted as well as software as a service.